# GWT view navigation basic example

Tags: gwt, user-interface

I have a Navigation panel with `Back`/`Forward` buttons ( Function not important,  just want to get my head around swapping Panels in and out of a GWT page )

**NavigationButtonsPanel**

```
public class NavigationButtonsPanel extends HTMLPanel
        {
            private Button btnA = new Button("Go back");
            private Button btnB = new Button("Go forward");

            public NavigationButtonsPanel( )
            {
                super("Navigation Panel");
                add(btnA);
                add(btnB);
            }

            public void setBackHandler( ClickHandler handler )
            {
                btnA.addClickHandler(handler);
            }

            public void setForwardHandler( ClickHandler handler )
            {
                btnB.addClickHandler(handler);
            }
        }
```

I then have 3 basic panels,  A B and C which use this.  My Navigation from A-B-C and back to B-A works fine.
I now simulate a user changing something before they go to Panel B. In this case a Label in PanelB.
My final app will obviously be more complex than this but would this be typical of how an app would work.  You modify some fields in a Panel through a users interaction in the same panel or a different one,  load the new panel,  more interaction, load in different panel etc?
I will only want a user to use a very well defined navigation path so there is only one path to a certain panel.

**PanelA**

```
public class PanelA extends HTMLPanel
{
    private static PanelA panel;            
    private PanelA()
    {
        super("Panel A");
        final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

        NavigationButtonsPanel btnPanel = new NavigationButtonsPanel();
        btnPanel.setForwardHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
            {
                rootPanel.clear();
                PanelB.setMessageFromPreviousPage("Message set in Panel AAAAA");
                rootPanel.add( PanelB.getInstance() );
            }
        });

        add( btnPanel );
    }

    public static PanelA getInstance()
    {
        if (panel == null)
        {
            panel = new PanelA();
        }
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**PanelB**

```
    public class PanelB extends HTMLPanel
{
    private static PanelB panel; 
    private static String messageFromPreviousPage;

    private PanelB()
    {
        super("Panel B");
        final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

        Label messageLabel = new Label(messageFromPreviousPage);


        NavigationButtonsPanel btnPanel = new NavigationButtonsPanel();
        btnPanel.setBackHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
            {
                rootPanel.clear();
                rootPanel.add( PanelA.getInstance() );
            }
        });

        btnPanel.setForwardHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
            {
                rootPanel.clear();
                rootPanel.add( PanelC.getInstance() );
            }
        });

        add( btnPanel );
        add(messageLabel);
    }

    public static PanelB getInstance()
    {
        if (panel == null)
        {
            panel = new PanelB();
        }
        return panel;
    }

    public static void setMessageFromPreviousPage(
            String message)
    {
        messageFromPreviousPage = message;


}
    }
```

**PanelC**

```
public class PanelC extends HTMLPanel
        {
            private static PanelC panel;            
            private PanelC()
            {
                super("Panel C");
                final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

                NavigationButtonsPanel btnPanel = new NavigationButtonsPanel();
                btnPanel.setBackHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
                    {
                        rootPanel.clear();
                        PanelB.setMessageFromPreviousPage("Message set in Panel CCCCCC");
                        rootPanel.add( PanelB.getInstance() );
                    }
                });

                add( btnPanel );
            }

            public static PanelC getInstance()
            {
                if (panel == null)
                {
                    panel = new PanelC();
                }
                return panel;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Any idea why Panel B does not update its UI?
```

Because when first time `PanelB` instance created using `PanelB.getInstance()` , then  `messageLabel` created and it also set value. while you are calling second time same method from PanelC after changing the message, At that time, it's using same instance of `PanelB` instead of new object. and as per your coding, you are changing the value of `messageFromPreviousPage` variable instead of label text. so you didn't find any changes on UI.

If you want to change the label text, then declare `messageLabel` as a globel variable static and change label. i.e.

```
 private static Label messageLabel;
 private PanelB() 
{
//your code
}
 public static PanelB getInstance()
{
    if (panel == null)
    {
        panel = new PanelB();
    }
    else
    {
        messageLabel.setText(messageFromPreviousPage); //Require to set Text Again
    }
    return panel;
}
```